# Consider the 4-to-1 multiplexer shown below. What values must inputs A, B, C, D be so that the multiplexer implements the function

Tags: boolean-logic, multiplexing

I am completing some practice quizzes online in preperation for a uni exam next week, and I am a bit stumped as to how to solve this problem:

> Consider the 4-to-1 multiplexer shown below. What values must inputs
>   A, B, C, D be so that the multiplexer implements the function
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

If anyone would'nt mind giving me a few tips as to how to solve this, I would much appreciate it.

Thanks
Corey

Comment: The last function element is unreadable. `X=s1*~s0+s0*?`

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume: `X = S1 * ~S0 + S0 * ~S1` as your posted picture is unreadable.

First you need to know the multiplexor transfer:

```
S1 S0 X 
 0  0 A 
 0  1 B 
 1  0 D 
 1  1 C
```

Then, apply the function to all your possible input combinations.

```
f(s1,s0)=S1*~S0+~S1*S0

f(0,0) = 0
f(0,1) = 1
f(1,0) = 1
f(1,1) = 0
```

And finally fill the table with `X=f(s1,s0)`

```
S1 S0 X  f(s1,s0)
 0  0 A  0
 0  1 B  1
 1  0 D  1
 1  1 C  0
```